# Javascript async function never returns

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, redis, sequelize.js

I'm trying to run a simple program that pulls from Redis and inserts into a database. This program never seems to exit, can someone point me in the right direction?

```
require('newrelic')

const client = require('./config/redis')
const models = require('./models')
const sequelize = require('sequelize')

async function flushTweets() {
  try {
    var tweets = await client.lrangeAsync('writer', 0, 100)
    client.ltrim('writer', 0, 100)
    if (tweets && tweets.length > 0) {
      tweets = tweets.map(tweet => JSON.parse(tweet))

      models.Tweet.bulkCreate(tweets, { returning: true });

      for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; ++i) {
        models.User.update(
            { numTweets: sequelize.literal(`"Users"."numTweets" + 1`) },
            { where: { id: tweets[i].user.id }
        });
      }

    }
  } catch (e) {

  }
}

flushTweets();
```

Comment: add some `console.log` in there to determine where it apparently "halts"

Comment: It reaches the end of the try function, I'm thinking that the promises are never resolved...

Comment: so you've determined that `bulkCreate` and all the `models.User.update` run? have you put a console.log in the `catch` to see if there's an error?

Comment: Yes, they both run, and there are no errors.

Comment: Are both models.User.update and models.Tweet.bulkCreate sync or aysnc?if it is async you should await them to be in sequence. And try atleast an empty return.